# Why self delegate is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, delegates

I want to make a weather application by adding a city name with openweathermap api. But I could not send the city I added in AddCityViewController back to HomeViewController. Because, self?.delegate is nil, in AddCityViewController.swift

```
 @objc private func didTapSaveButton() {
    print("clicked save button")
    
    if let city = cityTextfield.text {
        
        let weatherURL = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(city)&APPID=b4251cb51691654da529bccf471596bc&units=imperial")!
        
        let weatherResource = Resource<WeatherViewModel>(url: weatherURL) { data in
            
            let weatherVM = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherViewModel.self, from: data)        
            return weatherVM
        }
        
        Webservice().load(resource: weatherResource) { [weak self] result in
            if let weatherVM = result {
                
                if let delegate = self?.delegate {
                    delegate.addWeatherDidSave(vm: weatherVM)
                    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the prepare function in HomeViewController.swift was not getting called.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    guard let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else {
        fatalError("NavigationController not found")
    }
    
    guard let addWeatherCityVC = nav.viewControllers.first as? AddCityViewController else {
        fatalError("AddWeatherCityController not found")
    }
    
    addWeatherCityVC.delegate = self
    
}
```

What I want is, I want to pass the city name back to HomeViewController when user press the save button.

```
extension HomeViewController: AddWeatherDelegate {
   func addWeatherDidSave(vm: WeatherViewModel) {
      print(vm.name)
   }  
}
```

***[Source code in GitHub](https://github.com/bilaldurnagol/Fit_Weather_Swift5)***

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of your code, please include code in your question itself.

Comment: i edited again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using segue for navigation, so the prepareForSegue method won't get triggered. In your code, you are manually initialising an instance of `AddCityViewController` and presenting it. So to fix the issue, you have to set delegate to that instance.

```
@objc private func didTapAddButton() {
   let vc = AddCityViewController()
   vc.title = "Add City"
   vc.delegate = self
   let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
   nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   present(nav, animated: true)
 }
```

Or else you can use segue for navigation.